# Dynamic creation of database during an user event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to create a database in rails dynamically. I wants to create a new database for each user account in my application. When a user is registered a separate database should be allocated for that user. I came to know about the dynamic creation of tables and maintaining separate rake task for multiple database in a single rails application.

Comment: `rails` application listens to one `db` at runtime. I think what you are trying to achieve can be done by implementing a `multi-tenant` system.